# Any good reason why my Unix & Linux "accounts page shows all my Stackexchange accounts except my very Unix & Linux one?

Tags: support, stackexchange, user-accounts

When I have a look at [my accounts page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/8038/alain-pannetier?tab=accounts) in my Unix & Linux profile, I cannot see my Unix & Linux account.

I don't think it's an openId problem because it also shows up in the profile and the list of accounts clearly shows that SE "knows" I have all these accounts.

Here is a screenshot of my profile page.  It says "Registered User" and the openId is recognised as identical as in my other SE accounts.

[image]

Comment: Is it deliberate that your english-SE account has a link to your blog, and the other don't? If not, can you copy it's profile *to all SE accounts* and see what happens.

Comment: It was deliberate because the presentation part should be tailored to each community.  I've followed your suggestion and quite logically, all my profile was copied to other accounts, to the notable exception of... U&L.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No particular reason; our identity system is denormalized and sometimes account associations can be overlooked.

On the accounts tab of your user page, I clicked "clear all associations", then "associate" and this seemed to clear it up.

(for anyone else reading this, you must have at least one credential in common on all Stack Exchange sites for us to be able to link them up, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a thousand times @Jeff.  I did not dare to do that myself. Worked very well. Long time fan.

Comment: BTW @Jeff @Alain, the "clear all associations" button... is there anyway this could be reworded? It seem to be quite... I can't put my finger on it. Perhaps the folks over at [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) could comment on this fairly abrupt prompt.